# set default zoom level on mapView

Tags: android

i have made a seekbar zoom controler for my map view as follows

```
myZoomBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.zoombar);
        SetZoomLevel();
        myZoomBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myZoomBarOnSeekBarChangeListener);
```

and

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener myZoomBarOnSeekBarChangeListener =
           new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
              boolean fromUser) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             SetZoomLevel();
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
         };

         private void SetZoomLevel()
         {
          int myZoomLevel = myZoomBar.getProgress()+1;
          mc.setZoom(myZoomLevel);
          Toast.makeText(this,
           "Zoom Level : " + String.valueOf(myZoomLevel),
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         };
```

my question is how can i set the default view level to 15? As it is right now when the map opens it is zoomed out all the way.

Comment: are you asking how to set zoom to levele 15 when the map is displayed intially

Comment: yes so when you open the map the zoom is set at 15 and the slider can be moved from there if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code

```
MaView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.my_map);
MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(15);
```

Comment: are you sure that your mapcontroller is fetched from Mapview

Comment: if i do this

    `p = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000), (int) (longitude * 1000000));
    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(p);
    myZoomBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.zoombar);
    SetZoomLevel();
    myZoomBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myZoomBarOnSeekBarChangeListener);
    mc.setZoom(15);`

it sets the view to 15 but the seekbar still shows 0 is there a way to set it at 15 as well?

Comment: what your problem zooming of mapview or seekbar position if later is the case post your xml for seekbar

Comment: Thanks for the hint added `android:progress="15"` to the XML and all works the way i need.

Answer (score 0):

Use setZoom() method of MapController class in your MapActivity .

Comment: if i add `mc.setZoom(15);` it doesn't do anything